# Ignore typescript overload error

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following error when i am compiling my Typescript project

```
Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.
```

The error is occuring here

```
function setTimeout(callback: any, time: any = 1, timeInSeconds: boolean = false): void
```

Well of course i googled and found out that this is caused by my function name `setTimeout` as setTimeout is already reserved by the browser api and typescript wants to tell me that i cannot overload it.

The reason for my question here is that my code will never run in any browser. Its ment to run in a node-like environment created by myself using C# & [Javascript.NET](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net). Its not crucial as the code still compiles and works perfectly but these errors are annoying me more and more. So my question is can I somehow ignore this error or even better can I specify the libraries the compiler thinks I have myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look in

```
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0
```

showed me that all browser apis are defined in

```
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\lib.d.ts
```

so since I commented out

```
declare function setTimeout(handler: any, timeout?: any, ...args: any[]): number;
```

it compiles without errors